# Calling a static method on an abstract class outside the main method

Tags: java, main-method

**This program works with no problems**

```
public class Test{
static int DAY_IM = 1000*60*60*24;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2004,0,7,15,40);
    long day1 = c.getTimeInMillis();

    for (int i  =0; i < 15 ; i++) {

        day1 += (DAY_IM *29.52);
        c.setTimeInMillis(day1);

        out.println(String.format("full moon on %tc ",c));
    }

}
```

I want to understand why when I move this line

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Outside the main method, and inside the class then use reference `c` I can't find any method of Calendar class

I understand that Calendar class is abstract and this returns an instance of a subclass to assign to the reference, but why can't I use the reference to reach the methods outside the main method?

Comment: why would you want to move it outside the main method? Are there several other methods that you are not showing of the Test class?

Comment: For future questions: include the problematic code, not just "working code", and post the actual compiler error or runtime exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you move `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();` outside the main function you're creating NON static variable in class `Test`

to use this variable in static method `main` you need to write something like this:

```
new Test().c.METHOD_NAME
```

another option is to add `static` to variable declaration, then you will be able to use it in main directly

Comment: Okay but when i moved this line i also used the reference outside the main method so what the problem here ?

Comment: @Muhammad how do you use it?

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   
 c.set(2004,0,7,15,40);

imagine that there's no else code and i wanted to use only these two lines but outside the main method when i use c. as a reference i get nothing

Comment: @Muhammad code must be within some function/method, only variable initialization are allowed